# File Error while running Simple Flask program

Tags: python, flask

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-6-5b3985f98f53>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('D:/document/VIT/Internship/IBM Externship/Notebooks/flask/first.py', wdir='D:/document/VIT/Internship/IBM Externship/Notebooks/flask')

  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "D:/document/VIT/Internship/IBM Externship/Notebooks/flask/first.py", line 3, in <module>
    from flask import Flask

  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\flask\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from .app import Flask

  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 32, in <module>
    from werkzeug.wrappers import BaseResponse

ImportError: cannot import name 'BaseResponse' from 'werkzeug.wrappers' (D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\wrappers\__init__.py)
```

> This is the error I'm getting. I'm quite new to Flask and was trying to run the program as shown below:

```
from flask import Flask
app= Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
 
def index():
    return "Henlooo"
if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(debug=False)
```

Please tell me what I need to change in the file that was listed

Comment: Try to update werkzeug.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Uninstall using `python -m pip uninstall werkzeug` then run `python -m pip install werkzeug` if there is a particular version required for your project run `python -m pip install werkzeug==2.0.3` remember to change the version to yours.

https://github.com/mjmeijer/donald_2021/issues/4